# Make likewise use password file first for logins

Tags: linux, pam, likewise-open, nsswitch.conf

Is there a way I can make likewise check the passwd file first?  Currently, nsswitch.conf does say files first.  However, when I tried to log into the box as the root user, it was hanging until I removed the network cable.  This was as direct login to the console, so it was a reverse ssh lookup or anything like that.

Something in pam perhaps?

Comment: I would think that with files listed first it would work... any chance there's been a reboot since you changed the order? (assuming that you did) not that that makes sense or should be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out /etc/pam.d/system-auth... pam controls authentication, nsswitch.conf does the looking up of uid->name mapping, groups, etc.  You'll want the unix pam modules to come before the likewise pam modules.